# Arrange multiple divs how best to handle layout

Tags: html, css

Basically, what I would like to do is to lay out some divs in a master div to simulate a table.

The only difference is that sometimes a "column" needs to be a different size depending on the "row". So I'm trying to figure out how best to position the divs. Should I float the divs, abs position, etc...

I just thought of another way. Should I make one div per row and then each "column" a span?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say in order to get the div's arranged as a table you'd want to:

Make your master div have CSS style be something like this:

> position:absolute;
>   top:0px;
>   left:0px;

Your top-left cell would have a style something like this:

> position:relative;
>   top:10px;
>   left:10px;
>   width:50px;
>   height:100px;

This will make the first cell located 10px from the top-left and it would have the dimensions 50px wide and 100px tall.

Next, your top-right cell would have a style like this:

> position:relative;
>   top:10px;
>   left:70px;
>   width:50px;
>   height:100px;

This would position the top-right cell 10px from the top and 70px from the left of the master div (which would be 10px from the right edge of the top-left cell).

You can probably logic out the locations of subsequent cells.  make sure your `top` and `left` values take into account the total distance from the top and left of the master div.

Answer (score 4):

If you're just wanting to output a small amount of data, why not use a table? Tables are OK for tabular data.

Comment: This is for laying out all the subsections of a very large form. So its not really tabular data. Plus the irregular column with is really needed to make everything work.

Answer (score 2):

You can carry forward your thought of putting a div for each row and span for each column. This will make the arrangement an irregular table, the row-heights are regular and the column-width is irregular.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the content of your "column" using a `span` for your "column" markup may not work. `div` is a block-level element, and `span` is an inline-element. Inline elements cannot contain block-level elements. So semantically, I would recommend against using `span`.

What you are wanting is basically a grid layout system. There is [a CSS3 working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid/) for this, but naturally it isn't yet implemented. You may want to look at grid layout systems like [blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/), [yui-grids](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/index.html) or [960gs](http://960.gs/).

Answer (score 0):

If the data is tabular data (which includes forms IMO), then use a table, that's what the table tag is for, surprisingly enough.

If you want to create columns then you would just float them to the left, and add a padding or margin to separate columns. You can attach multiple classes to each div to target specific situations like making one column a bit wider.

Comment: I would normally suggest a table to do this kind of thing, but from the description, it sounds like there could different column widths in each row - this is not something a table could handle.